подскажите пожалуйста как правильно запускать файлы с++ с отладкой g++ и выводите результат во внешнюю консоль cmd
постоянно возникают вот такие ошибки о том что файл outDebug.exe уже открыт 
либо открывает кириллицу


Этот вопрос похож на: при запуске отладки и сборки g++ возникает ошибка, при это изначально код запускался. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit] и поправьте вопрос.

Надо удалять/завершать/убивать ранее запущенные программы. Не надо дублировать вопросы. Не надо задавать вопросы картинками.
